# RxJS: What is the proper way to emit a void value as an init one?

Tags: rxjs, concatenation, void

In [the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-b4j726?embed=1&file=index.ts) you can see that in case you need an initial value for a stream of the void type it looks incorrect.

```js
import { of, fromEvent, concat, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map, switchMap, take, finalize } from "rxjs/operators";

let sequence = 1;
const trigger = new Subject<void>();
const source = concat(
  of(""), // is there any way to make it more pretty?
  trigger
).pipe(
  switchMap(() =>
    fromEvent(document, "click").pipe(
      take(3),
      finalize(() => {
        sequence++;
        trigger.next();
      })
    )
  ),
  map(
    ({ clientY }: MouseEvent) => `sequence: ${sequence} clientY: ${clientY}!`
  )
);

source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith

Comment: @ritaj this one is deprecated

Comment: It's not. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4772

Comment: @ritaj https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-b4j726-urgs6y?file=index.ts non-working. `startWith('')` - the same...

Comment: `startWith(undefined)`

Comment: I think a better option is using `of(void 0)` or `startWith(void 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a "prettier" solution than this:

```
const source =
  trigger.pipe(
    startWith(undefined as void),
    switchMap(...),
    ...
  );
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-b4j726-4exx93?file=index.ts yeah, looks a bit better :)